# Change of Odds ratio?

Tags: time-series, logistic, odds-ratio

I want to see the relation between the division of household tasks and family stability in Sweden by Logistic regression method. First, in the analyses, persons with an egalitarian division of HH show a lower odds of intention to break up than persons with the traditional division but by adding the variable of satisfaction with the division of household tasks to the model the Odds of egalitarians increases to more than traditional.

How can I explain it?